# What purple items have Samuel Jackson's characters had?

Tags: props

Samuel Jackson's (Mace Windu's) purple lightsaber was supposedly at his behest because that's his favorite color.  Are there other conspicuously-purple items that Jackson's characters have had?

Comment: In Turbo, his character, Whiplash, is a racing snail that has purple eyes and purple neon lights.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000168/bio), "his characters often feature the color purple", including the following:

- Mitch Hennessy wore a purple-violet gem ring in [*The Long Kiss Goodnight*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116908/) (1996)
- Mr. Glass wore purple clothing in [*Unbreakable*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0217869/) (2000)
- Jackson chose to have Doyle Gipson wear a purple hat in [*Changing Lanes*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0264472/) (2002)
- Mace Windu, upon request by Jackson to George Lucas, wielded a purple light saber in [*Star Wars: Episode II - Attack of the Clones*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0121765/) (2002) and [*Star Wars: Episode III - Revenge of the Sith*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0121766/) (2005)
- Lazarus, Jackson's character in [*Black Snake Moan*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0462200/) (2006), plays a purple Gibson guitar.
- Neville Flynn at one point was carrying around a [blue and purple snake](http://cbsnews1.cbsistatic.com/hub/i/r/2006/08/11/d463d4e3-a642-11e2-a3f0-029118418759/thumbnail/620x350/ccdfcf275b3be38027a0ff2613772ef5/image1886146x.jpg) in Snakes on a Plane (2006).